# How to set background color for input text?

Tags: html, css

```css
.field {
  float: right;
  width: 170px;
  height: 23px;
  font: normal 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 6px 24px 6px 6px;
  background: #c1caca;
  margin: 25px 10px
}
.search {
  background: url(../images/search-icon.png) right no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="field search ">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: by text box you mean input?

Answer (score 0):

`background` of `search` was overriding the color and background color is given with `background-color` and not with `background`

```css
.field {
  float: right;
  width: 170px;
  height: 23px;
  font: normal 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 6px 24px 6px 6px;
  background-color: #c1caca;
  margin: 25px 10px
}
.search {
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="field search ">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific when using two `background-image` and `background-color` or the propery will be overwritten

```css
.field {
    float: right;
    width: 170px;
    height: 23px;
    font: normal 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 24px 6px 6px;
    background-color: #c1caca;
    margin: 25px 10px
}
.search {
    background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/48362.png);
    background-size:32px;
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:36px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="field search ">
    </form>
</div>
```

Or you can use background color and image in same place

`background:#c1caca url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/48362.png) no-repeat right;`

```css
.field {
    float: right;
    width: 170px;
    height: 23px;
    font: normal 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 24px 6px 6px;
    margin: 25px 10px
}
.search {
    background:#c1caca url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/48362.png) no-repeat right;
    background-size:32px;
    padding-right:36px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="field search ">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Your solution is here


   `.field{
   float:right;
   width:170px;
   height:23px;
   font: normal 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   padding:6px 24px 6px 6px;
   background:url(http://www.sitewelder.com/art2012/logo-big-searchoptimization.png)right no-repeat;
   background-color:yellow;
   background-size: 40px 40px;
   margin:25px 10px }`

    http://jsfiddle.net/recobee/rg9tnsox/
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use background-image css property and "background-position" property

```html
<input style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x25/f00')" type="text" >
```